# htaccess is not ignoring images like it should?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file that is supposed to be redirecting any non-existing files/folders/etc into the application's index.php script where they are handled by the application's SEO rewriting.

The problem is that any missing images are also redirecting into the application which is causing a lot of additional load and is unnecessary. I've been attempting to get this htaccess file to ignore images, but even though this **should** be working, it's not, and I'm completely out of ideas as to why...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L]
```

When I make a request to http://www.domain.com/folder_that_doesnt_exist/image.jpg this redirects to index.php

When I make a request to http://www.domain.com/folder_that_does_exist/image.jpg it **also** redirects to the index script

I'm not sure what I'm missing here because unless OR is specified, shouldn't the RewriteRule only be applied if the request passes **all** of the RewriteCond statements? which it clearly should not be passing...

**Update:**

I've modified the code to the following just to eliminate possible issues, but it still redirects all non-existing images into the script...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L]
```

Comment: get rid of the `.*` at the beginning, also try `REQUEST_FILENAME` instead of `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: I've tried both of those, unfortunately and neither of them are working either. I've added the modified code I used for testing to the post.

Comment: do you have anything else in the .htaccess? are you sure it is being processed correctly? (try to add `deny from all` at the top and see if you get 403)

Comment: The file is being processed correctly, but it's still not working...

Comment: The only other content in the htaccess file are a few comments, which I removed just in case they were causing issues, and that didn't change anything as expected. I'm completely baffled by why this isn't working since I've even seen code like this in htaccess files for Joomla and shopping cart software to prevent attempting to remap image files and it works fine there. We even have some sites using those applications running on this exact same server with no problems.

Comment: Add `-MultiViews` to the Options statement and `,NS` to the rewrite rule flags.  This may be being matched on a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maby try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: I updated the file for this and it still doesn't appear to be working. That does seem like the right track to take though, by attempting to match requests for invalid images and remap them to a 404 error, but it still doesn't seem to be catching the image requests for some reason.

Comment: I've tested yesterday on my localhost and when there was a request to image which doesn't exists it showed 404 error. When image existed it was displayed correctly. When there was request to http://127.0.0.1/something-not-image then index.php was served. So it should work. Maby in one of your subfolders you have another `.htaccess` which overwrites this one?

Comment: Ok so this is an interesting development. I've done some further testing and it seems the first rule works fine if I remove the second. But as soon as I add the second back in, it starts throwing missing images into the application again... Which makes no sense because the [L] flag is set to tell mod_rewrite to ignore the remainder of the rules after it matches that one... If anyone has any idea why it would be ignoring this flag, please let me know because I've never run into something like this before

Comment: I think it's not ignoring this flag and rewriting correctly. If i recall correctly, after rewriting anything .htaccess is parsed again to check if rewritten path matches something inside `.htaccess`. It goes like that after every rewrite, until limit or no rewrite rule matches. My example works, why don't you use it ?:)

Comment: I wish I could but when I paste that content into my htaccess file, it still redirects images into the index.php script. I've noticed though that if I replace the image-specific code with a redirect to a blank file that **does** exist on the server, they correctly redirect to it. I've suspected that what you're saying is probably happening that the image rewrite is triggering another rewrite which is hitting the catch for the index.php script. The question in my mind now is how do I get around that :\

Comment: If you paste my rules into .htaccess (and nothing more) it still redirects not existsting images?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I think somehow the line matching it is getting reprocessed by mod rewrite and ending up being redirected into the index script. I've also tried a variant of the file to cause the index.php redirect to only occur if the image matching line does not match by adding it to that rules list with a ! prefix, but even then it still redirects to the index script. I'm starting to get the feeling that there's something funky happening on this specific server, so I'm going to have to do some more testing on a different server as these rules should have been working correctly.

Comment: I revisited this issue and had an epiphany. The cause of the problem was in fact a recursion of the htaccess rules being caused by a server misconfiguration. There was no "default" 404 error page set up in apache for the account. So what was happening was image requests were being handled "normally" which resulted in a missing .shtml file which then redirected into the application because it was not looking for a missing image file. Although my original htaccess file now works correctly after adding the default error page, I'm accepting this answer as the code here is also correct.